QGIS Overlap analysis and R terra::intersect do not give the same results
I have performed an Overlap analysis between a Vector layer of classified values (Slope) and a series of smaller vector layers generated from KDE analysis. The aim was to produce a table with the overlapping area of each KDE value with the classes in the first vector layer (slope).
In QGis I loaded the slope layer into the project and the different layers to overlap. Then I used the Overlap tool (QGIS version 3.38 Grenoble) which produced said table. Columns were the different KDE layers, rows the values of the slope layer.
To double-check I redid the analysis using the terra package in R. Here I used terra::intersect to achieve the overlap. I retrieved the values using terra::values and the area using terra::expanse then I joined the two sets into a table. Here is a reproducible example of the code:
library(tidyverse)
library(terra)
library(BAMMtools)
    
pathshp <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra")
v <- vect(pathshp)
v2 <- aggregate(v, dissolve=T, by="NAME_1")
writeVector(v, "testdata.gpkg")

raster <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
rvals <- values(raster, mat=F, dataframe=F, na.rm=T)
jenks <- getJenksBreaks(rvals, 4)
m <- c(jenks[1], jenks[2],1,
       jenks[2], jenks[3], 2,
       jenks[3], jenks[4], 3)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc1 <- classify(raster, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
jenks.poly <- as.polygons(rc1, dissolve = T)

writeVector(jenks.poly, "testdata_jenks.gpkg")

t <- intersect(jenks.poly,v2)
tvals <- values(t, mat=F, dataframe=T, na.rm=T)
texp <- expanse(t)
tint <- cbind(tvals,texp)

After analyzing my entire dataset I have now two tables from both processes. While the overall results are comparable there are deviations of about 0.001 – 0.05 % for each value.
While the discrepancy does not influence the results in a way that would alter their interpretation, it keeps nagging.
After having checked the process with the newly generated above example code, it seems to work, at least the values of the overlap are the same, wether calculated in QGIS or in R.
I guess I have a problem with my datasets. I will report, if I find the problem.

Impossible to be sure without your data but the sf package (which terra might be using) can work with spherical geometry while QGIS is using planar geography - switch spherical geometry off using sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE) and see if you get different answers in R and if they equate to QGIS'...

Thanks for the suggestions. I tested it, but it gives me the same values also with spherical geometry switched off.

Righto, is there some way you can generate sample data (preferably in R, so you can share the generating code) which you can replicate your results? Save as GeoTIFF and GeoPackage for input to QGIS.

Just wrote a reproducible example. With these example data everything works. I will look further to any mistakes I might have in my process.
